# Do we have canvas Modified Event in Fabric.js?

Tags: events, html5-canvas, fabricjs, undo-redo

In Fabric.js we have Object modified events like object:modified. Do we have similar event for the entire canvas.

Actually I am trying to implement undo and redo features. I am saving the canvas as JSON if something happens on it and loading it again for undo feature.

Do we have any better solution for this features in Fabric.js?

Comment: How do you expect this event to be different from "object:modified"? "object:modifed" covers all cases of modification on canvas, since any modification implies object change (except something like canvas background color, but that's usually not supposed to be part of undo/redo)

Comment: When we are adding any new objects to canvas object:modified event is not firing. It is firing only when we perform modifications(scaling,rotating etc) on  any added object.

Comment: You can use "object:added" and/or "object:removed" for that — http://fabricjs.com/events/

Comment: @kangax Those events don't appear to be triggered on setBackgroundColor, setHeight, or setWidth actions.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to check for added/removed objects too. You could implement it like this:

```
var canvasModifiedCallback = function() {
console.log('canvas modified!');
};

canvas.on('object:added', canvasModifiedCallback);
canvas.on('object:removed', canvasModifiedCallback);
canvas.on('object:modified', canvasModifiedCallback);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is better explained in this [link](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events). Use it this way:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) { // or 'object:added'
  var activeObject = e.target;
  console.log(activeObject.get('left'), activeObject.get('top'));
});
```