# Sending multiple objects forward changes their order (z-index)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

The following snippet has a green square above a red square

1. Select both squares by dragging over them.
2. Click the `bring forward` button

After clicking `bring forward` the squares have switched order. It is my understanding that the items should stay in the same order, but be moved increasingly above other non-selected items as the button is further clicked.

If you deselect, and repeat the experiment you will see that they switch again.

Any ideas?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', 
{
  preserveObjectStacking : true
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10, top: 10,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100, height: 100,
  hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect);

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 40, top: 40,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 100, height: 100,
  hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect2);

$("#bringForward").click(function()
{
 var items = canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.getActiveGroup();

 if(items)
  items.bringForward();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="bringForward">Bring Forward</button>

<canvas id="c" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're going to have to work it out for yourself (i.e. which individual ones are selected and which aren't, and then move them keeping track of the selected ones order).

Comment: I'm happy to mock something up if you'd like...  you'll need to start here, `canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);`, by creating a selected event so you know the selected objects...  then bring forward, `canvas.bringForward(canvasSelectedItem, true);` send backward... etc.

Comment: @TimHarker This is more an illustration of a bug to the developers. I've also posted this question on their git page with a link to this question. Happy for you to attempt to answer the question though!

Comment: Sure.  They have a ton...  unfortunately.  But they also have a ton of great code that I've managed to work with.  I'm putting this website together, [http://xpressclocks.azurewebsites.net/create](http://xpressclocks.azurewebsites.net/create).  If you add multiple shapes and/or text and then right click you'll see a context menu for bring forward etc.  Haven't implemented multiple select due to its complexities.  I'll try to mock something up in the next day or two...

Comment: @TimHarker Yes, I'm working my way through a sandbox as we speak. Finding bugs as I go. Your site is coming together nicely. I did spot an odd bug when you have multiple text items and you then undo. It sometimes gives you 2 text items that are identical. Not sure if you're aware...

Comment: Thanks.  Yep.  Undo needs work...  I'm aware...  Just need to get it live and try to make some money first though, been going at it a while (in the evenings).  I noticed some of your other fabricjs stackoverflow posts along the same lines.

Comment: I've implemented an undo/redo facility using https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch Takes a lot of the pain out of it! Happy to give you a heads up if you like.

Comment: I took a quick look...  interesting!!!  Mine come from here, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043219/undo-redo-feature-in-fabric-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043219/undo-redo-feature-in-fabric-js).

Comment: I mean, having 2 objects both on top of canvas, select them and ask to send them on top is weird. I guess is an unwanted behaviour, simply you should not do the action if the objects are the topmost.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi But the trick is to know whether you have a selection that will cause this problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be considered a bug or not, depending on what do you expect the function to do.

The documentation for the feature says:
`Moves an object or a selection up in stack of drawn objects`
And is actually doing so.
The object on top cannot go more on top, the one under can and goes.

Still for a dev this can look like a weird behaviour, to me not really. But  guess is personal.

Here is your widget with a modified snippet to try a better solution.

```js
var removeFromArray = fabric.util.removeFromArray;

// modified function to avoid snapping
fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype.bringForward = function (object, intersecting) {
      if (!object) {
        return this;
      }
      var activeGroup = this._activeGroup,
          i, obj, idx, newIdx, objs, latestIndex;

      if (object === activeGroup) {
        objs = activeGroup._objects;
        latestIndex = this._objects.length;
        for (i = objs.length; i--;) {
          obj = objs[i];
          idx = this._objects.indexOf(obj);
          if (idx !== this._objects.length - 1 && idx < latestIndex - 1) {
            newIdx = idx + 1;
            latestIndex = newIdx;
            removeFromArray(this._objects, obj);
            this._objects.splice(newIdx, 0, obj);
          } else {
            latestIndex = idx;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        idx = this._objects.indexOf(object);
        if (idx !== this._objects.length - 1) {
          // if object is not on top of stack (last item in an array)
          newIdx = this._findNewUpperIndex(object, idx, intersecting);
          removeFromArray(this._objects, object);
          this._objects.splice(newIdx, 0, object);
        }
      }
      this.renderAll && this.renderAll();
      return this;
    };


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', 
{
  preserveObjectStacking : true
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10, top: 10,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100, height: 100,
  hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect);

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 40, top: 40,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 100, height: 100,
  hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect2);

var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 70, top: 70,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 100, height: 100,
  hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect3);

var rect4 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100, top: 100,
  fill: 'orange',
  width: 100, height: 100,
  hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect4);

$("#bringForward").click(function()
{
 var items = canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.getActiveGroup();

 if(items)
  items.bringForward();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="bringForward">Bring Forward</button>

<canvas id="c" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```