# Fabricjs - Implementing undo/redo on canvases

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, implementation, undo-redo

I am a newbie in vue and fabricjs and currently working on a complex application which deals with large amount of data.
I have multiple canvases with different objects, which may change based on user interaction.
All the changes/objects are being stored in the array of objects

Demo: https://prkos.csb.app/
[image]

I am trying to implement undo/redo in my application.
I have a hard time understanding the fabricjs undo/redo approach in the below answer (link)

[Undo-Redo feature in Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043219/undo-redo-feature-in-fabric-js)

What I think from the above answer (link) is that it deals with single canvas at a time with multiple objects inside it, but in my case, my canvas objects are stored inside an array of objects and which will be modified accordingly based on users interaction like adding colour, adding text, adding rect which will be performed on all the canvases at a time and undo should be reflected on all the canvases. In short, I have multiple canvases with the same objects inside it).

I have tried the below non-fabric approach, where the undo, redo works on a history index, which will be changed based on undo (increment pointer), redo (decrement pointer) concept.

Based on this approach I am calling a mutation where

```
apply(state,actiontype){
if(actiontype==undo){
           remove the respective objects
           pop(data) //pops the data out of other places in the application not the history
           historyindex++;
}else if(actiontype==redo){
           get the data from history
           unshift(data);
           historyindex–-;
}
}
```

I feel this is not the most efficient way to perform undo/redo operations, as it includes cloning objects and even it has to handle huge sets of data. Which might lead to freezing of the application. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Code:(Multiple Canvases) https://codesandbox.io/s/test-project-prkos?file=/src/components/App.vue

Edited: I have updated the example with undo/redo functionality, used fabric-history library, still trying to find a better approach.

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438316/implementing-undo-redo-in-fabricjs-with-multiple-canvases

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the command pattern for this. It will be more efficient than using all json data. For that, you need to implement the next approach:

1. Create a class for storing History. It's may be look like this

```
class CommandHistory {
  commands = [];
  index = 0;
  getIndex() {
    return this.index;
  }
  back() {
    if (this.index > 0) {
      let command = this.commands[--this.index];
      command.undo();
    }
    return this;
  }
  forward() {
    if (this.index < this.commands.length) {
      let command = this.commands[this.index++];
      command.execute();
    }
    return this;
  }
  add(command) {
    if (this.commands.length) {
      this.commands.splice(this.index, this.commands.length - this.index);
    }
    this.commands.push(command);
    this.index++;
    return this;
  }
  clear() {
    this.commands.length = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    return this;
  }
}

// use when you init your Canvas, like this.history = new CommandHistory();
```

2. Then you must implement the command classes for your commands.

For adding object

```
class AddCommand {
  constructor(receiver, controller) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.controller = controller;
  }
  execute() {
    this.controller.addObject(this.receiver);
  }
  undo() {
    this.controller.removeObject(this.receiver);
  }
}

// When you will add object on your canvas invoke also this.history.add(new AddCommand(object, controller))
```

For removing object

```
class RemoveCommand {
  constructor(receiver, controller) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.controller = controller;
  }
  execute() {
    this.controller.removeObject(this.receiver);
  }
  undo() {
    this.controller.addObject(this.receiver);
  }
}
```

The fabric.js has the saveState method for every object http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#saveState. And you can use it for implement transform command, that will be add to the history objecct when you will modify your fabric object on canvas.

```
class TransformCommand {
  constructor(receiver, options = {}) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this._initStateProperties(options);

    this.state = {};
    this.prevState = {};

    this._saveState();
    this._savePrevState();
  }
  execute() {
    this._restoreState();
    this.receiver.setCoords();
  }
  undo() {
    this._restorePrevState();
    this.receiver.setCoords();
  }
  // private
  _initStateProperties(options) {
    this.stateProperties = this.receiver.stateProperties;
    if (options.stateProperties && options.stateProperties.length) {
      this.stateProperties.push(...options.stateProperties);
    }
  }
  _restoreState() {
    this._restore(this.state);
  }
  _restorePrevState() {
    this._restore(this.prevState);
  }
  _restore(state) {
    this.stateProperties.forEach((prop) => {
      this.receiver.set(prop, state[prop]);
    });
  }
  _saveState() {
    this.stateProperties.forEach((prop) => {
      this.state[prop] = this.receiver.get(prop);
    });
  }
  _savePrevState() {
    if (this.receiver._stateProperties) {
      this.stateProperties.forEach((prop) => {
        this.prevState[prop] = this.receiver._stateProperties[prop];
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can add your commands in your history and execute or undo them.