# How to detect that Fabric canvas was changed

Tags: fabricjs

Is there an easy way to detect that any objects in a canvas were added/changed/deleted? A method like `canvas.wasChanged()`. I need to detect that after re-creating a canvas with `loadFromJSON`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507291/do-we-have-canvas-modified-event-in-fabric-js - see if this can be of any help

Comment: Thanks. I ended up saving the original JSON and comparing with a JSON created after the user potentially changed the canvas